# Is it okay to use gigantic length of table tag to generate QR code if I care about SEO?

Tags: html, seo

I'm using the plugin to generate QR code.
It should generate QR as image, however it generates as table like the code below.

Then this QR code is up to 1800 lines.
For now I'm putting this code in the top of the page contents.
In my guess, Google robot will be getting tired of analyzing this gigantic useless Table tag.

Should I remove this QR code table? or It doesn't really matter?
Anyone has any idea about this?

```
<div class="qrcode">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td class="black"/>
        <td class="black"/>
        <td class="black"/>
        <td class="black"/>
        <td class="black"/>
        <td class="black"/>
        <td class="black"/>
            .
            .
            .
        <td class="black"/>
        <td class="black"/>
        <td class="white"/>
        <td class="white"/>
        <td class="white"/>
        <td class="white"/>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Out of interest, is there any reason why it (mis-)uses a `table` instead of generating an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Google robot will be getting tired of analyzing this gigantic useless
>   Table tag

Googlebot will not get *tired* of indexing your page. However, Google search result list includes pages on which the searched keywords were located not further than **520 KB** from the start of the page. So if you put lots of "*useless Table tag*" in the beginning of the page and the relevant content will be located after 520 KB then your search results will be affected.

Please have a look on [Search Engine Indexing Limits: Where Do the Bots Stop?](http://www.sitepoint.com/indexing-limits-where-bots-stop/) article which describes limitations of different web spiders.

But long pages with *useless code* can also affect your customers' experience. It is very likely that long page will take more time to display. Increasing page load time by even  100ms (which seems to be not that much) might be *dangerous* for your website.

Please check [Milliseconds are Money](http://www.carbon60.com/milliseconds-are-money-how-much-performance-matters-in-the-cloud/) article to get more details on that. A few quotes from that article:

> The big guys in the cloud industry have really dug deep and proved
>   that those milliseconds matter:
>
> - For every **100ms** increase in load time of Amazon.com decreased sales by **1%** (Kohavi and Longbotham 2007).
> - Google discovered that a change from loading a 10-result page in 0.4 seconds to a 30-result page loading in 0.9 seconds decreased traffic and ad revenues by 20% (Linden 2006).

I hope that will help you to make right decisions regarding your website page structure.